# Overlaying R county map onto a state map

Tags: r, maps

R newbie here.

If I first use `map('state')`, how can I then use `map('county', ylim=..., xlim=...)` but offset it like this:

[image: overlay]

Right now, I am using imagemagick's `composite -gravity southwest ...` to combine 2 PNG files, but this seems less than ideal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `fig` option in a graphics parameter call to set the region where a figure will be plotted.

```
map("state")
par(fig=c(0.1,0.9,0,0.6), new=TRUE, xpd=NA)
map("county",regions="california",add=TRUE)
```

In regards to the other code, `xpd=NA` lets you plot in the margins of a plot while `new=TRUE` makes sure you don't scrap the existing plot when starting a new plot. Adding `add=TRUE` to the end of the plot for the county acts similarly to the `new=TRUE` call.

[image]