# How to create a map inside a map in R

Tags: r, maps, gis

I'm trying to create a figure with a large map of a section of the Australian coast, with a smaller map inset showing the whole of the continent in the top right corner. The problem is that when I run the code for the inset, it appears in right place, but the first map disappears.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
install.packages("maps")
install.packages("mapdata")
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
# create the main map
map("world2Hires",
    ylim=c(-17,-11),xlim=c(121, 126),
    fill=TRUE, col="grey")
maps::map.scale( 124.6,-16.65, ratio=FALSE, relwidth=0.15)
box()
# create the inset
par(fig = c(.60, 1, .60, 1), mar=c(0,0,0,0))
map("world2Hires",
    ylim=c(-40,-0),xlim=c(110, 155),
    fill=TRUE, col="grey")
box()
```

These are the maps I want to produce in a single image; the smaller in the top right corner of the larger:
[image: Main map] [image: top right inset]

EDIT:

following the thread linked by thelatemail, I tried using new=TRUE and add=TRUE as follows:

```
 # create the main map
map("world2Hires",
    ylim=c(-17,-11),xlim=c(121, 126),
    fill=TRUE, col="grey")
maps::map.scale( 124.6,-16.65, ratio=FALSE, relwidth=0.15)
box()
# create the inset
par(fig = c(.60, 1, .60, 1), mar=c(0,0,0,0), new=TRUE)
map("world2Hires",
    ylim=c(-40,-0),xlim=c(110, 155),
    fill=TRUE, col="grey", add=TRUE)
box()
```

However, the result is something a bit strange: 
[image]

Not sure what's going on. I obviously need to play with the margins to get the inset in the right spot, which is fine, but I don't know why it's not using my map coordinates for the inset.

Any insight would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10369253/496803

Comment: thanks for this. I've tried adding new=TRUE and add=TRUE, which puts the second image on top of the first, but instead of the whole map of Australia, it reproduces the section from the first map in the inset, not sure why it's ignoring my ylim and xlim commands. I'll edit my OP to show what I mean.